# Text tree in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tree, outline, nested-sortable

I'm looking for GUI feature that will be part of Python desktop application.

The feature is a **text tree** with **drag and drop** functionality between individual nodes.
Further I'd like to be able to **attach a note** with longer text to individual nodes in the tree. The **note** would be **switchable** to expanded or collapsed state.

It is exactly shown in [this](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) NestedSortable JQuery library except of the switchable note.

Could you show me what are the possibilities of contemporary Python GUIs according to this feature? I prefer lightweight GUI with modern look as in the JQuery example.

Which GUI would be the most suitable for this task? `Tkinter`, `wxPython`, `pyQt`, `pyGTK` or other? Or would you choose some GUI + `Javascript` libraries? Why would you prefer particular `GUI` to achieve requested functionality and lightweight modern design?

Comment: I think both recent PyGTK and PyQT provide for this.

Comment: @9000 This is what I wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyQT has a good solution for this with its QTreeWidget or a MVC setup.  QTreeWidget is simplest:

Here's a small example using PyQt4

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.treewidget = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.treewidget.setHeaderLabels(['a'])
        self.treewidget.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.treewidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.treewidget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.treewidget.resize(300,300)
        self.titems = []
        for i in xrange(100):
            if not i%10:
                pitem = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treewidget,["Parent %d"%i])
                self.titems.append(pitem)
            else:
                item = QTreeWidgetItem(pitem,["Child of %d"%i])
                self.titems.append(item) 
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you for code in `PyQT`. I've done something similar in `wxPython` but don't know how to achieve the look similar to NestedSortable. I'm trying to implement easy outliner (like www.workflowy.com) and the trees in all python frameworks look rather as the are for some file manager. My aim is the result will look different. The structure of information is OK, but the look is not what I'd like to achieve. Are there some possibilities to make the UI look better?

Comment: I'm interested in in which GUI framework I have better possibilities to achieve the look approaching NestedSortable look. It's more pleasant for the eyes than traditional desktop look like in this example.

Comment: You can really do anything you want visually with Qt, just know that mimicking web based GUIs will likely involve some custom work on your end (google images 'custom qtreeview example' for some nice examples).  I'm a former wxPython user, but I was unhappy that some things crash for no reason on certain wxWidget builds with Linux (ironically enough, the modelview was what kept crashing on linux). Here's a good link to read on:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html
and
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html
has some great examples and views.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and yet some Javascript possibilities in Python (this two approaches seem to lead to target) and then ask another question if it will need some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [etetoolkit](http://etetoolkit.org). Its much simpler.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: can you elaborate?  It looks much more complicated